# Git: difference "git rebase origin/branch" VS "git rebase origin branch"

Tags: git, rebase

Does anyone know what is the difference? Seems to me, it is the same. But when I run it, it didn't do the same thing:

`git rebase origin/branch` - ok rebases from remote branch

`git rebase origin branch` - makes conflicts

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
git rebase <upstream> <branch>
```

is equal to

```
git checkout <branch>
git rebase <upstream>
```

By default `<branch>` is `HEAD`.

[1] https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html

Answer (score 77):

@Mar's answer is right and perfectly solved this question, just add one comment.

if you want to rebase a branch based on remote master branch, `git rebase origin/master` is not enough, it will not get new commits directly from origin/master. You need to `git fetch` before `git rebase origin/master`.

or you can use another way to rebase a branch.

1. switch to master `git checkout master`
2. `git pull origin master`
3. switch back to your own branch `git checkout {your branch}`
4. `git rebase origin/master`

then, your branch is updated to newest commits.

Comment: is there a difference in 4th step with : `git pull origin/master --rebase`  ?

Comment: Just learned this one but `git checkout {your branch}` can actually be `git checkout -` if the last branch you were on was yours

Comment: @nerdlyist the same logic as `cd -`.

Comment: @thoroc that is awesome

Comment: `git checkout {your branch}` -> `git rebase origin/master` -> `git push` I think it does the same thing, am I right?

Answer (score 15):

The last step should be: `git rebase origin/master`