# Git: Fix repo with a branch and its remote on different branches

Tags: git, branch

I have no idea how this happened, but I have a git repo in the following kind of state:

```
A--B--C--D  master
    \
     E--F   origin/master
```

The commits `E` and `F` are at this point obsolete; the changes they make on `B` have no relevance and they can be deleted if necessary.

I only keep the `origin` remote as a backup for my code, and nobody else has cloned it, so I can use whatever brute force I need.

What would be the cleanest way to clear this up?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git: difference "git rebase origin/branch" VS "git rebase origin branch"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29164321/git-difference-git-rebase-origin-branch-vs-git-rebase-origin-branch)

Comment: `git push -f origin master` will sync `origin/master` on `D`, then `E` and `F` will become candidates for garbage collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only keep the origin remote as a backup for my code, and nobody else has cloned it, so I can use whatever brute force I need.

In that case, `git push --force origin master` will suffice.  Be *very sure* you're OK with `origin/master` in your repository, and `master` in the (separate) Git repository over on `origin`, being no-longer-able to find commit `F`.

(Your own repository will remember both commits `E` and `F` for some time, under the *reflog name* `origin/master@{number}`, so as long as you keep your own repository intact, you can still get them back if they turn out not to be obsolete after all.  However, at some point they will really be removed.  The *server* may not have reflogs at all and its copy of commits `E` and `F` may go away relatively quickly—in seconds, or hours, or just a few days, for instance.)

#### How and why this works

Every Git repository has *its own* branch names, which are semi-private to that particular Git repository.  There is a repository over on the machine you're calling `origin` and it has a branch name `master`.

Your *remote-tracking names,*<sup>1</sup> such as `origin/master`, are your Git's method of remembering what some *other* Git has as its *branch* names.  In this case your `origin/master` is your Git's memory of `origin`'s `master`.

When you have your Git call up their Git, via `git fetch` or `git push`, the two Gits have a startup conversation.  It's slightly different for fetch and push, but you can observe what `git fetch` will itself observer using `git ls-remote`.  Just run `git ls-remote origin` (or leave `origin` out as the default is usually `origin` anyway): your Git will spill out the *other* Git's branch, tag, and other names that it listed.  That's the first part of a `git fetch`: your Git phones up their Git and gets this listing.

When you use `git fetch`, your Git uses this listing to ask their Git for any commits and other internal Git objects that they have, that you don't, that your Git would like to have.  For instance, if you didn't have commit `F` yet, and your `origin/master` remembered commit `B` or `E` instead, and they have commit `F` as their `master`, your Git will say: *I'd like to have commit `F` please* and they'd add that to a list of commits to send.  They'd then offer commit `E`—a Git *must* offer the parents of each commit—and your Git would either say *no thanks, I have that already* or *yes please* (in which case they would offer `B`, `E`'s parent, and so on).

Their fetch process then bundles up whatever is needed to get those commits to your Git—this is where you'll see `counting objects` and `compressing objects`—and sends that over.  Your Git expands those so that you have a proper set of commits and their data, and then creates or updates your `origin/master` based on the hash ID stored in *their* `master`: now that you definitely have commit `F`, your Git can make your `origin/master` point to it.

Hence, if you run:

```
git fetch origin
```

at any time—this is the "get me everything" form of the command—your Git will call up their Git and get the preliminary "everything" listing.  The two Gits will figure out from there what your Git needs to get, and give it to your Git.  Your Git will then create or update *all* your remote-tracking names based on *all* of their branch names.

When you use `git push`, which is as close as Git gets to the opposite of `fetch`—the pair are `push` and `fetch` rather than `push` and `pull` due to a historical mistake<sup>2</sup>—a similar process occurs, but there are two key differences:

- Your Git sends, rather than receives.  (Your Git still chooses what to send, and the "must offer parent if sending commit" still holds, and so on, but with `git fetch`, their Git sent and your Git received.)
- At the end, instead of some Git updating some sort of "remote-tracking name", your Git asks (politely) or commands (forcefully) their Git to *set* some of its *branch* names.<sup>3</sup>

If you ask or command them to set their `master`, and they obey, your Git now knows that their `master` is set to the hash ID you provided, so your Git now updates your `origin/master` remote-tracking name.

When you use a gentle, ask-type `git push origin master`, your Git sends commits you have that they don't—such as `C` and `D`—and then asks them politely: *Please, if it's OK, set your `master` to point to commit `D`?*  They will say *No!  If I do that, I'll forget commit `F`!*  This error comes back as the Git jargon words *rejected* and *non-fast-forward*, but it just means they said no, as that would lose commit `F` and hence `E` as well.

But that's precisely what you want them to do.  So you just need to send them a forceful command: *Set your `master`!*  They could still refuse—if you don't have permission, for instance—but of course you do have permission so in this case they will obey, and lose commit `F`.

There are two force modes for `git push`: `git push --force` is the ancient version, and `git push --force-with-lease` is a more-modern (since Git 1.9 or so) variant.  The difference between these is that `--force` just says *set*, but `--force-with-lease` says: *I think your `master` is _____.  If so, set it to _____ and let me know that you did; if not, tell me I was wrong and don't set your `master` after all.*  The first blank gets filled in with your Git's `origin/master` value: your Git's memory of their Git's `master`.  So that gives you the ability to be sure that you're having them throw away exactly what you think they will throw away.

If you're the only *user* of the other Git, there's no need for the care that `--force-with-lease` adds: what you think is right, *is* right, by definition.  But if you're concerned that you might be forgetful (e.g., if you use two different laptops and can't remember which one was up to date), you can use the fancier check-first-then-force `--force-with-lease`.  It's never *wrong* to use `--force-with-lease`, and except for the fact that the old `--force` is the historical default, `--force-with-lease` really should be the default.

---

<sup>1</sup>Git calls these *remote-tracking branch names* but I decided some years ago that the word *branch* in here is useless clutter that creates some extra confusion, so I now just call them *remote-tracking names*.

<sup>2</sup>Often, after fetching commits, you'd like to *integrate* those commits.  That's what `git pull` does: it runs `git fetch` to *get* commits, then runs a second Git command to *integrate* those commits.  This seemed, early on, like the correct natural granularity, so `git pull` was the user-facing command that was the opposite of `git push`.

It turns out, though, that it's often important to separate the fetch operation from the integrate operation, inserting some sort of *inspect* operation in between, for instance, so as to choose the *correct form* of integration.  Mercurial got this right and Git got it wrong: in Mercurial, `hg pull` means what Git means by `git fetch` and you have to add a separate operation, or an extra flag, to `hg pull` to make it also do an integration step.

<sup>3</sup>You can choose what names you ask them to set, so you can make your Git ask or command tag names to be set, or some other kind of name, but in general, the usual case here is "branch name".